# How to run several queries in a loop and save that data into a dataframe?

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, sqldf

I am attempting to run several SQL queries through R, each differing by one search parameter (Zip code), run a few simple computation on each of the results, and then save the findings onto a new data frame.

I'm using a for loop to do the SQL query and I'm having no issue when it comes to doing my computations, but at the end of the code, all I am receiving is a data frame with one row duplicated for the entire length of the data frame.

I am thinking that the problem lies with how I pass my final computations (dataframe:Togetic) into my end result (dateframe: Togekiss), but I haven't been able to correctly address the issue.

Here is my code:

ALLZIP is a list of all of the zip codes that I'm working with.
I removed my computations for the sake of brevity.

```
#Sample ALLZIP
ALLZIP <- c(10453,10457,10460,11238,11004)

ALLZIP<-as.data.frame(ALLZIP)

#Storage
Togekiss <-as.data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow = 15, ncol=length(ALLZIP$ALLZIP)))
names(Togekiss)<-ALLZIP$ALLZIP

j <- 1

for(i in (ALLZIP$ALLZIP)){

  print(i) 
  Togepi = sqlQuery(dbhandle,query=paste0("SELECT RaceCode,COUNT(*) AS 'num'FROM [DIS_SYNDROMIC].[dbo].[PatientVisits]WHERE YEAR([AdmissionDateTime])=2016 AND Zip LIKE '",ALLZIP$ALLZIP[1],"' GROUP BY RaceCode ORDER BY 2 DESC"))
  Togepi <-as.data.frame(Togepi)

  Togepi$RaceCode <- gsub("BL|OT|B|2056-0|AA|2052-9|2075-0","2054-5",Togepi$RaceCode)
  Togepi$RaceCode <- gsub("1004-1|1840-8","1002-5",Togepi$RaceCode)
  Togepi$RaceCode <- gsub("2041-2|2045-3|2031-3|2034-7|2039-6|AS|2032-1|2044-6|A|2037-0|2035-4|2033-9|2048-7|2050-3|2049-5|2051-1|2042-0|2030-5|2029-7|2040-4|2043-8|2038-8|2046-1|2047-9","2028-9",Togepi$RaceCode)
  Togepi$RaceCode <- gsub("2096-6|2091-7|2082-6|2500-7|2093-3|2076-8|2079-2|2087-5|2090-9|2088-3|2086-7|2081-8|2101-4|2098-22036-2|2100-6|2097-4|2080-0|2094-1|2089-1|2104-8","2076-8",Togepi$RaceCode)
  Togepi$RaceCode <- gsub("OT|O","2131-1",Togepi$RaceCode)
  Togepi$RaceCode <- gsub("WH|W","2106-3",Togepi$RaceCode)

  Togepi<-tapply(Togepi$num,Togepi$RaceCode, FUN=sum)

  #Getting a new data frame

  EL<-sum(Togepi["1002-5"],Togepi["2028-9"],Togepi["2054-5"],Togepi["2076-8"],Togepi["2131-1"],Togepi["2106-3"])

  Togetic<-c(Togepi["1002-5"],Togepi["2028-9"],Togepi["2054-5"],Togepi["2076-8"],Togepi["2131-1"],Togepi["2106-3"],sum(Togepi)-sum(Togepi["1002-5"],Togepi["2028-9"],Togepi["2054-5"],Togepi["2076-8"],Togepi["2131-1"],Togepi["2106-3"]),sum(Togepi),(Togepi["1002-5"]/sum(Togepi))*100,(Togepi["2028-9"]/sum(Togepi))*100,(Togepi["2054-5"]/sum(Togepi))*100,(Togepi["2076-8"]/sum(Togepi))*100,(Togepi["2131-1"]/sum(Togepi))*100,(Togepi["2106-3"]/sum(Togepi))*100, ((sum(Togepi)-EL)/sum(Togepi))*100)
  Togetic<-as.data.frame(Togetic)

  rownames(Togetic)<-c("American Indian or Alaska Native ","Asian","Black or African American","Pacific Islander","Other","White","No Info","Total","Percentage American Indian","Percentage Asian","Percentage Black or African American","Percentage Pacific Islander","Percentage Other","Percentage White","Percentage Missing")


  colnames(Togetic)<- paste0(ALLZIP$ALLZIP[i])

  Togekiss[,j]<-Togetic
  j <- j+1 
}

rownames(Togekiss)<-c("American Indian or Alaska Native ","Asian","Black or African American","Pacific Islander","Other","White","No Info","Total","Percentage American Indian","Percentage Asian","Percentage Black or African American","Percentage Pacific Islander","Percentage Other","Percentage White","Percentage Missing")

Togekiss<-round(Togekiss,digits=2)
```

Comment: The outcome of your computation in Togetic is a single line that has to be combined with all other zip postal codes in one big data.frame right? Can you put a small example of ALLZIP in your question? I think I got a nicer solution for you.

Comment: Sure thing. ALLZIP looks like this:

    ALLZIP <- c(10453,10457,10460,11238,11004)

And it keeps on going for 150 more zipcodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I don't know how your `Togetic` looks like, but if that is indeed a single row which should be added to a data.frame/matrix this might be a viable option:

```
ALLZIP <- c(10453,10457,10460,11238,11004)
ALLZIP<-as.data.frame(ALLZIP)
allZipCodes <- apply(ALLZIP, 1, function(zipcode) {
  # Each zipcode here is basically ALLZIP[i,1]
  Togepi = as.data.frame( sqlQuery(dbhandle,query=paste0("SELECT RaceCode,COUNT(*) AS 'num'FROM [DIS_SYNDROMIC].[dbo].[PatientVisits]WHERE YEAR([AdmissionDateTime])=2016 AND Zip LIKE '",
                                          zipcode, #this is ALLZIP$ALLZIP[i]
  "' GROUP BY RaceCode ORDER BY 2 DESC")) )
  colnames(Togetic) <- zipcode
  return(Togetic) # This would be the row you wanted to update in Togekiss.
})
# allZipCodes contains a list of all your calculations, by executing a function on each of these elements with do.call we can get a combined matrix.
do.call(rbind, allZipCodes)
```

Can you try this and let me know if it works? If it doesn't can you show me what is in `Togetic`?

Comment: I get an error:
    'Error in apply(ALLZIP, 1, function(zipcode)){:
    dim(x) must have a positive length'

I'll update my code to show what exactly is 'Togetic'.

Comment: This was based on ALLZIP being a `data.frame`, I'll update my answer.

Comment: The error I get this time around is:
`Error in match,names(clabs,names(xi)) :
names do not match previous names`

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your dataframe with each loop iteration. Try using this instead of `Togepi = sqlQuery() Togepi <-as.data.frame(Togepi)`

```
temp.df = sqlQuery(YOUR SQL HERE)

if(i==1)
  {Togepi <-as.data.frame(temp.df)}
else
  {Togepi <- rbind(Togepi,s.data.frame(temp.df)}
```